# Can't find xgettext. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed

Tags: gettext

When I run manage.py makemessages -l en at the root of my Django project, I get the message

> Can't find xgettext. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or
>   newer installed.

I work on windows 8. I have unzipped gettext-runtime-0.17-1.zip and gettext-tools-0.17.zip in C:\Program Files (x86)\gettext-utils and I have updated the PATH.

In my project settings.py, I have updated the LOCALE_PATHS.

And still, I get the error message.
What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the cmd window by closing and opening it again.